# How do you determine whether a zip entry is a folder or a file?

Tags: php, zip

### ️ Code source

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip_path = './test.zip';

if($zip->open($zip_path))
{
  for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++)
  {
    $file_path = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    if(<MY ISSUE HERE>)
    {
      // If is directory
    }
    else
    {
      // If is file
    }
  }
}
```

### ⛔ The Issue

I've searched from [ZipArchive PHPDoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php), but I can't figure how to determine whether the `$file_path` returned by `$zip->getNameIndex($i)` corresponds to a directory or a file.

`$zip->statIndex($i)` return doesn't contain that information.

```
Array
(
    [name] => foobar/baz
    [index] => 3
    [crc] => 499465816
    [size] => 27
    [mtime] => 1123164748
    [comp_size] => 24
    [comp_method] => 8
)
```

Thanks in advance for your time ❤️

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ziparchive but maybe checking if its a directory by looking at a trailing slash at the end of the name ?

Comment: Seconded, a trailing slash seems to be the only mechanism for this. (And perhaps also check for `size = 0` if you want to be double secret extra sure?)

Comment: So.. what happens when someone put an empty file named `file/` in your zip. It's surprising that ZipArchive has no method to check if the item is a directory or a file.

Comment: Maybe that will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824221/how-to-get-the-zip-files-directory-structure-in-php ?

Comment: @DylanKAS What happens is that you have an invalid entry in the zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking to see if the last character of the name is a slash.

Note that it is not required for zip files to have entries for the directories. The directory structure is implied by the path names of the *files* in the zip file. A directory entry (with a trailing slash) is there, if desired, to save and restore the attributes of that directory, such as permissions.